# What decides which pathway-forming neurons relate to a given thought or behavior?

Tags: neuroscience, neural-network, neuroanatomy, plasticity

So I know pathways of neuron connections are what store or “activate” behaviors, memories, information, etc and relate to specific thoughts and other brain functions occurring, and that when we learn something new we form (or strengthen) new connections/pathways. But among all the neurons in the brain, or even just those within a certain section, what decides which of those individual neurons are the ones to form a path that corresponds to encoding a particular memory or information?

Is every neuron distinct in the information it “holds” or signals? Is it just a matter of transmitters and receptors? And could we (or a molecule), in search of the pathways for a certain memory or thought, identify a particular neuron that should be connected to it—aka if every neuron IS unique, is that expressed in its structure (or genes, proteins, etc)?